# Evaluating negative numbers using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having a problem evaluating Negative numbers with Powershell.
In this example -0.36 should have been less than -0.01. So $Bad_Note should be 0 and not 1

```
$Note = "0, -0.36"
$Markup_Discount = ($Note -split ',')[1].trim()
$Markup_Discount 
$Bad_Note = 0
if ($Markup_Discount -gt -0.01) {$Bad_Note = 1}
$Bad_Note
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to compare a [string] with a [float].
Just add [float] before the string to convert this one in float (but take care you need to be sure it will work).

Like this :

```
$Note = "0, -0.36"
$Markup_Discount = [float]($Note -split ',')[1].trim()
$Markup_Discount 
$Bad_Note = 0
if ($Markup_Discount -gt -0.01) {$Bad_Note = 1}
$Bad_Note
```

Or this one (as you want) :

```
$Note = "0, -0.36"
$Markup_Discount = ($Note -split ',')[1].trim()
$Markup_Discount 
$Bad_Note = 0
if ([float]$Markup_Discount -gt -0.01) {$Bad_Note = 1}
$Bad_Note
```

Have fun :)